# example code of sorting & pagination in map reduce mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, search, mapreduce

**Hello All,**
I need a working example code of map reduce in MONGODB with pagination & sorting.
Please, comment the link.
because i just frustrated from finding the *sorting & pagination* example code.

Please help me.

Comment: Search google for "MongoDB paging"? Also Map Reduce? You would never do it in MR

Comment: Why would you NEVER do it in map/reduce? if you have millions of documents, and want to map/reduce those to 100s, you may still want to paginate those 100s of results into pages!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

MapReduce is the wrong tool for this. You can implement pagination by chaining a normal find-query with [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/), [skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/).

To query the documents 101-120 by `date`from a collection, use this:

```
db.collection.find().sort(date: -1).skip(100).limit(20);
```

Comment: My Query is made by map reduce .. That is why i asked _WITH MAP REDUCE_ ..
i tried find method but it is useless in my documents so, map reduce is giving very fast & accurate results which i wants .  But there is just option in mongo document for sort but it also not works ..

Comment: Agree with post creator, question was about other...For our case skip/limit also not ok, due to performance issues, but map-reduce looks good.